# Runtime 9 error after workbook opens CSV successfully

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

I have a VBA macro that opens IBM cognos to run a report and save it out as a CSV file. The macro then opens the file and copy pastes it into my excel workbook.

On

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "S:\Supply Chain\Scheduling\NBVI\buf.csv"
```

I get Runtime Error 9: subscript out of range after the workbook opens.

This same code works in other workbooks and I'm at a loss.

Comment: Kinda hard to start debugging the situation without seeing a redacted portion of the CSV that reproduces the error but you should be opening CSV files with the [Workbooks.OpenText method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx), not the [Workbooks.Open method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195811(v=office.11).aspx).

Comment: Added .OpenText still have the same error.  Its not a portion of the CSV that causes an error. It opens the workbook like VBA tells it too but before going on it says Runtime 9 out of range. Im new at VBA, I always thought runtime 9 was when It cant find the file or create the object you ask it too.

Comment: If I copy and paste the code into another workbook and run it I get an Object defined error instead of Runtime 9

Comment: You could use the method I describe here: [jkp-ads.com/articles/importtext.asp](http://jkp-ads.com/articles/importtext.asp) and then on the workbook containing the connection, just refresh that connection.